# Magento Admin + CasperJS + TravisCi

Tags: admin, adminhtml, travis, casperjs

I've tried to test my admin-module with casperjs. Locally all my test are passing but on travis some of theme are failing.

Has anyone of you ever worked with this combination of tools + magento?